# How can I set Raspberry Pi keyboard layout with a one line command?

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

During installation I just want to run a set of commands and not do all the settings with `raspi-config`.

How can I set the keyboard layout just with the **command line** without any further interaction / UIs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Keyboard Configuration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/236/simple-keyboard-configuration)

Comment: If you use ctrl-shift-x in raspberry pi imager, the keyboard setting can be set there - best way to do it "during installation"

Comment: @Dougie I also saw that post but wanted something without any interaction / clicking / typing

Answer (score 2):

I figured out this `sed` command line to set e.g. german keyboard layout:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/XKBLAYOUT="[a-z][a-z]"/XKBLAYOUT="de"/' /etc/default/keyboard
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this via `raspi-config nonint do_configure_keyboard`. E.g. `raspi-config nonint do_configure_keyboard us` sets the US keyboard layout.

Reference: [Where can I learn about the raspi-config noint parameters?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105276/24404)